# Preserve filters in Firefox DevTools Network tab

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

When I'm working with devtools -> network, I'm adding some domain filters there.
How I can preserve that filters when close and reopen devtools?
I'd like to not enter them every time I'm opening devtools -> network.

Comment: Have you added a feature request in firefox for this? I too have a nice filter that excludes requests I don't care about during development. e.g. `OPTIONS` and requests to the Analytics service. It's a pain to keep the filter somewhere and have to paste it in all the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple but unfortunate answer is that the DevTools do not preserve any filters when closing them. And there is currently (as of Firefox 85) no option that controls that.

I assume one reason for that is to keep the memory footprint of the DevTools as small as possible when they are not required.

Having said that, there is an [existing feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1835264) for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to mention, I noticed that in Chrome it preserves the filter data there ...